# Why is assembly printing stuff other then what I asked?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data  
A:      .ascii  "Helloe-"
delim:  .byte   '-'  


.text
# t0 = add(A), t2 = add(delim)
main:

    la $t0, A               # t0 = add(A)
    la $t2, delim           # t2 = add(delim)

    li $v0, 4              # print string
    la $a0, A
    syscall
```

The output is `Helloe--`. It's like `A + delim`. I just want `A`. What's wrong here? Is it because add(A) contains the delim as well? Somehow, if I put the delim declaration above `A`, then it works.

Comment: You need a zero byte to signal the end of the string. Use `.string` or `.asciz` or put a zero byte manually (whichever your assembler supports) Alternatively, use a `write` syscall that takes a length as argument.

Comment: @Jester thank you that fixed it